# My NAS shows empty in Windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, nas

My wife accidently pulled the power supply from our Seagate GoFlex NAS. Most of it is backed up, but not all.

When I navigate to Network in Windows 10 I can see GOFLEX_HOME (which is how I used to access the drive). Within this, the root folders still exist, but the public folder (where my data used to be) is empty.

I then checked in the web interface (by navigating to the IP of the NAS in a browser) and I saw a message showing me that I have 931.51GB of data, and 0B free.

A browse of the web interface also shows me the names of all my files/folders which I can access, proving the data is there.

Thinking it had something to do with it having 0M left on the NAS hard drive, I deleted a few GB of data on the NAS. The same issue persists.

Oddly, our streaming music player can still play the songs from the nas,  but both W10 machines cannot see the file contents.

Is there anything I can do to access my data via File Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to copy all the data to another drive and reformat to start again when I thought of 1 more potential fix.

What would happen if I were to turn it off.... and on again. OK, to be fair, it was more about turning it off and leaving it off for an hour and then then turning it on. I guess during this time some thing has been reset because now, I can see all my files in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize what youve said:

- NAS knows its got data
- NAS streams over DLNA(or other) just fine
- CIFS/SMB isnt working

This points that the drive and master file table are probably intact, but the CIFs/SMB daemon that runs on the NAS has stopped/crashed.

1. SAFE solution: Pull the drive out and read it with a SATA drive dock. This will require you to buy one though.
2. Less safe option: Get the NAS to update its firmware (to the same version even) or factory reset its CONFIGURATION (Not format the storage). This should hopefully get the CIFs/SMB daemon back running again so the PCs can access it.

Comment: OK, now I've looked up what CIFS/SMB is working yes, that is right. However, is your solution simply copy the data, and then reformat? With option 1, the safe option, I don't understand how I can make the drive workable with Windows

Comment: If you go with option 1 the drive would appear like a USB key. Then you could backup and format the disk.

Comment: Ah I see, so both options does mean back up, reformat... meaning, restart. I was hoping to need to do this (although I will if I must) as if it did work, it can still work... A reformat must mean by reformatting it returns some software or a config file back to original settings... So if I *can* do that then no need to reformat. I won't hold my breath +1

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions No well suggestion 2 would in theory *reset* the NAS(the little computer running it) but leave the drive itself intact. Assuming the NAS has that functionality.

Comment: This was the same answer as SeaGate gave when I finally called them, essentially copy all the data, reformat and restart! I'll post my actual answer, but you deserve the bounty

Comment: Glad you got it resolved